# Error when trying to mock CakePHP 3 component

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, mocking, phpunit

I am trying to mock a CakePHP 3 component which checks if the user is allowed to view the page or not.

I tried this:

```
$authComponent = $this->getMockBuilder(App\Controller\Component\AuthorizationComponent::class)
    ->getMock();

$authComponent
    ->method('isAuthorized')
    ->willReturn($this->returnValue(true));
```

However, when running the test, it says:

```
Trying to configure method "isAuthorized" which cannot be configured because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is static
```

Most probably I wrongly created the mock. Can anyone tell me how to do it correctly?

Comment: What does your component look like?

Answer (score 0):

Specify mocked methods with `setMethods()` before `getMock()`:

```
$authComponent = $this
    ->getMockBuilder(App\Controller\Component\AuthorizationComponent::class)
    ->setMethods(['isAuthorized'])
    ->getMock();
```